# Remove character or word from string in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Hey I want to remove character/word or sentence from string.

**For example**

```
val string = "Hey 123"
```

or

```
val string = "Hey How are you 123"
```

or

```
val string = "Hey!! How are you 123"
```

and **output**

```
string = 123
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to remove? Is it always the last word in the string? Is it always a sequence of digits? Is it any sequence of characters that's common to multiple strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the digits:

```
val result = string.filter { it.isDigit() }
```

Alternatively if you want to omit letters (and maybe also whitespace):

```
val result = string.filter { !it.isLetter() }
val result = string.filter { !it.isLetter() && !it.isWhitespace() }
```

Comment: great answer. Thanks a million